# ExtentSparkReporter type or namespace cannot be found, why is this happening? C#

Tags: c#, selenium, automated-tests, extentreports, selenium-extent-report

[ExtentSprakReporter type or namespace not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9twKE.png)I'm trying to generate extent reports for my project and ExtentV3HtmlReporter is deprecated. The extent website states that the replacement is ExtentSparkReporter. But, when I try to create a new instance of ExtentSparkReporter, the type or name space cannot be found. Not sure why it's not working. I was not able to find anything online to solve my issue.

```
ExtentSparkReporter extentSpark = new ExtentSparkReporter();
```

Answer (score 0):

Had this myself.  To fix it, I had to upgrade ExtentReports to version 5.0.0

https://www.nuget.org/packages/ExtentReports/5.0.0-alpha6

In Visual Studio open your terminal (View -> Terminal), go to your project directory and run:

dotnet add package ExtentReports --version 5.0.0-alpha6